# Heat dissipation of a Resistor

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, dissipation

When I was studying current electricity I found out that the amount of heat dissipating across a resistor is equal to the potential energy lost by an electron. Now I thought that a resistor provides an obstruction and electrons collide to lose energy. When an electron moves near a proton potential energy is lost even then, so how can we say the two are same?

Answer (score 2):

1. When an electron moves towards proton the potential energy loss , is converted into gain in kinetic energy. so no heat is dissipated.
2. when electrons are moving in resistors due to an electric external field, it's average speed until it collides  (Drift velocity) remains same to due to successive collision with lattice, so you see the kinetic energy of electrons in resistors are almost same , thanks to constant drift velocity at given temperature which is caused when potential difference are created at both ends.

so when electrons move across given potential difference across terminals of resistors, there is change in potential energy , but this change in potential energy is not compensated by change in kinetic energy of electrons(as it is almost constant), so the energy emerges out as heat

Comment: But if there is a potential difference electron will accelerate and drift velocity will change and so kinetic velocity will also change

Comment: @BlackSusanoo In a resistor the atoms are very close to each other ,even if electrons move it would move for very short distance say $dx$ until it collides with positive lattice , then work done by electric field or potential energy change for single electron ($ E.dx$) would be very less , because $dx$ is too small, so you see the change in kinetic energy for a single electron would then almost be nil,  and it would appear from outside that free electrons are almost moving with constant velocity.

Answer (score 0):

When electrons are far away from proton, it is at higher potential and when it comes near the proton, it gains kinetic energy by losing potential energy. As we know heat is direct measure of kinetic energy so the heat dissipated by resistor is equivalent as loss of potential energy of electrons.